# CMUDict normalized for word frequency

Tags: dataset, natural-language, language-models

I am trying to train a neural grapheme to phoneme (G2P) model on CMUDict, but I find that pretty soon its loss is barely decreasing. Also, when I train the model on a different similar-sized dataset (other language), which has repeated entries and only contains fairly common words, the loss decreases much better. Qualitatively, the second model also performs noticeably better for my application. I am looking for a dataset that somehow incorporates natural word frequencies to balance out CMUDict or a similar English G2P dataset.

Example: the rather common word 'you' appears as often as the uncommon word 'Ayacucho' in CMUDict, so they are 'weighted' the same in the model's training. For G2P'ing arbitrary sentences, excellent performance on the former word is much more desirable, while we don't care that much about the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply duplicating CMUDict entries by the frequencies listed in the free American English frequency list [FrequencyWords](https://github.com/hermitdave/FrequencyWords), but then scaled by 0.001 to reduce the total corpus size and completely discard very rare words. The results were improved manually by modifying some inconsistencies between the two corpora with very common words (such as where "don't" would simply be "don't" in CMUDict, but "don" and "dont" in FrequencyWords).